# Problems with my Docker Setup, xDebug and PHP Storm

Tags: php, docker, apache-storm

I had created a Developer Setup with Docker.
The Setup works fine but I can't debug my application with xDebug and PHP Storm.
Apache Settings and the php.ini will be loaded from my files.

Thank you for helping!

My docker-compose.yml

```html
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: www-xtrose-mysql
    image: 'bitnami/mysql:5.7'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=www-xtrose
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=www-xtrose
      - MYSQL_USER=www-xtrose
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=www-xtrose
    ports:
      - '10013:3306'
    volumes:
      - './docker/mysql/data:/bitnami/mysql/data'
  php:
    container_name: www-xtrose-php
    image: 'bitnami/php-fpm:7.4'
    volumes:
      - './www:/app:delegated'
      - './docker/php/php.ini:/opt/bitnami/php/etc/conf.d/php.ini:ro'
  apache:
    container_name: www-xtrose-apache
    image: 'bitnami/apache:2.4'
    ports:
      - '10011:8080'
      - '10012:8443'
    depends_on:
      - php
    volumes:
      - './www:/app:delegated'
      - './docker/apache/my_vhost.conf:/vhosts/my_vhost.conf:ro'
      - './docker/apache/certs:/certs'
volumes:
  www-xtrose-mysql:
    driver: local
```

My php.ini:

```html
display_errors=1
expose_php=0
max_execution_time=360
max_input_time=360
memory_limit=256M
upload_max_filesize=1G
post_max_size=1G
opcache.enable=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=2
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=32
opcache.memory_consumption=256
extension=imagick.so
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

**My PHP Storm Debug settings:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use some other port instead of 0011 on your server configuration in php storm? Just try 82
also try to enable xdebug.remote_autostart = true to find out maybe it is problem with path mapping and also put breakpoints to the first script that opens in your project (index.php probably) and let me know if it helps please.

Comment: @RomanKrut its the Port 10011.
I have change it on server and on the php.ini settings.
No effect :-(

Comment: Run php --version command on your server. Does it have xdebug extension? You should see it like this https://i.imgur.com/cShgw7T.png

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'am got it and it is really simple.
On Linux host.docker.internal is not supported.
Delete all servers and  server settings in PHP Storm.
Goto Settings->php->debug and add Port 9003 to Debug Ports.

php.ini:

```html
zend_extension = "/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
```

Thats it.
Thank you everyone helping

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but your final resolution post above doesn't seem to be complete. You said to add port 9003, but you don't configure it anywhere else. Should it be configured in php.ini too? Also, are you using your IDE key at all in the end?

Comment: Also, you didn't mention which of apt-get or pecl install you used to get your xdebug.so extension? Did you configure anything in xdebug.ini? If yes, what is its path? The only thing that works for me, if that xdebug appears in `php -m`